# I want to update only one value in database.but running this query update all row with null values rather then the value i update

Tags: java, sql, database

I want to update only one value in database.

But running this query updates all row with null values rather then the value I update.

```
String Insert_SQL= "UPDATE employee " +"SET Name ='"+Name+"', Father_Name='"+Father_Name+"', CNIC='"+CNIC+"', Contact='"+Contact+"',Address_Temp='"+Address_Temp+"',Address_Per='"+Address_Per+"',Occupation='"+Occupation+"',Salary='"+Salary+"'"+" WHERE ID = +A+";
```

Comment: It would be very helpful if you paste actual error stack trace.

Comment: Please instead of putting the string builder, can you put the final query as it is being ececuted?

Comment: Did you mean to concatenate the value of a variable A into the string? As written, +A+ is a literal part of the string.

Comment: Also the last part of your query should be " WHERE ID = '"+A+"'";

Comment: Please divide to short and having meaning subject, details in body. Use dot and commas, many people can't read long chaotic sentences